# Does anyone know how service bus 1.1 with TLS 1.2 will work in the load balancing environment?

Tags: azureservicebus

I am new to azure service bus.
I want to understand load balancing with service bus. We are using service bus 1.1 with TLS support 1.2 and in the code we are using version 2.1.0 of Azure.Service.bus.dll
In our environment we have multiple clients which will connect to load balancing server for further data processing. load balancing server uses 8 application servers and DB.

Do I need to install service bus across all 8 servers or how will I know which one is the host or how this will work?

Thank you.

Comment: Service Bus 1.1 is a [deprecated product](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/collaboration-and-federation-azure-service-bus-messaging-on-premises-futures/) out of support. Don't use it.

Comment: Thank you @SeanFeldman. There is already code written and now we want to add load balancing for it. The other option would be to upgrade it to the latest version. Cheers.